# NHibernate <sql-query> in hbm - Could not execute query

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an HBM file where I want to put and execute a raw sql query. This is what I put in my hbm file:

```
  <sql-query name="SqlSrcMyStuff" callable="true" >
    <return-scalar column="RU_ID" type="System.Int32" />
    <![CDATA[ 
          select some_id
          from some_table
          where param1 = ? and param2 = ?
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
```

This is my code:

```
IList listOfRules = objMyDAO.GetByNamedQuery("SqlSrcMyStuff", arrParams);
```

but I'm getting an exception "could not execute query". But when I take the query it's showing in the exception and replace the parameters and run against my database - the query executes fine.

How can I make this run my raw sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HBM should be

```
<sql-query name="SqlSrcMyStuff" callable="true" >
    <return-scalar column="RU_ID" type="System.Int32" />
    <![CDATA[ 
          select some_col  AS RU_ID
          from some_table
          where somecol1 = :param1 and somecol2 = :param2
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```

And a query

```
var result = session.GetNamedQuery("SqlSrcMyStuff")
        .SetInt32("param1", 1)
        .SetInt32("param2", 1)
        .UniqueResult<int>();
```

The result here shoul be just an int, not IList... because that is what we say (scalar as return)
Als check similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075498/1679310)

Comment: Thanks. I did it and now I'm getting "ORA-00911 invalid character" but when I run the query in db it runs. any ideas?

Comment: Not so much experience with, oracle, but that would be some small SQL statement adjustment... I guess. The above answer shows fully working solution for Sql sever. [e.g.](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00911.php) *PS: try to send query without params maybe, to be sure that something is working. But I would just guess here. As I said, for SQL Server, this standard NHibernate approach is working...*

Comment: found the solution - ends up there was a semicolon at the end of my sql query